# Why is the eventHub causing my Callback function not to be called in my Hyperledger code?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying the https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/SDK-Demo/blob/master/helloblockchain.js code that utilizes event handling.

In the setup part of the code, the following can be found:

```
for (var i = 0; i < peers.length; i++) {
    // Peers on Bluemix require secured connections, hence 'grpcs://'
    peerUrls.push("grpcs://" + peers[i].discovery_host + ":" + peers[i].discovery_port);
    chain.addPeer(peerUrls[i], {
        pem: cert
    });

   eventUrls.push("grpcs://" + peers[i].event_host + ":" + peers[i].event_port);

    chain.eventHubConnect(eventUrls[0], {
        pem: cert
    });

}
```

When I run the whole helloblockchain.js code, the message "Successfully submitted chaincode invoke transaction..." is displayed and the program stops.  I was expecting to see the message "Successfully completed chaincode invoke transaction..." to appear next but this did not happen.

To check what is causing the problem, I removed the following lines:

```
    chain.eventHubConnect(eventUrls[0], {
        pem: cert
    });
```

When I try it again, the code is working properly.

Based on this, the eventHub has a negative effect on the code.

However, I cannot afford not to use eventHub since I need to know if the invocation of my chaincode is successful or not. Is there a particular configuration that needs to be done to make eventHub work in HFC?

Comment: Have you checked the event port (listed in your ServiceCredentials) to make sure it's open? If so then can are you running this from the master branch? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: Hi @Chris.  I'm using the Bluemix blockchain service and I confirmed that the event port (31003) is open.  I'm using the master branch (https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/SDK-Demo/blob/master/helloblockchain.js) for the sample code.  I am using Windows 7 and HFC v0.6.5.  I already tested Ubuntu for this but got the same problem.

Comment: Can you switch your branch to git checkout b7d5195 and verify whether or not the problem still occurs?

Comment: Hi @Chris.  I tried this solution before and it worked.  However, this solution does not use chain.eventHubConnect.  I need to use an event listener in my HFC code to get the events sent by my chaincode.